# Conditionals within amin

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, min

I have two arrays `U` and `V`, both of shape (*f*, *m*). I will set *f* = 4, *m* = 3 in the example below.

I want to extract the minimum value of each column of `U`, subject to the corresponding value in `V` being nonnegative, i.e. for the j^th column, I want to return the minimal value of `U[i,j]` such that `V[i,j] > 0`.

My first attempt at this was:

```
import numpy as np

U = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
V = np.array([[1,-1,1],[1,1,1],[-1,-1,1],[-1,-1,1]])

mask = (V > 0)

np.amin(U[mask], axis = 0)
```

but this returns 1 (the minimum of the whole array), rather than `[1,5,3]`, the conditional, columnwise minimum which I'm looking for.

It seems like my issue is that `U[mask]` flattens out to being of shape (1, 7), which destroys the (4, 3) structure, and makes searching for the columnwise minimum impossible (apparently).

Is there a way for me to amend this code so that I can return the columnwise minimum I am looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `where` together with `iinfo`:

```
np.where(V>0, U, np.iinfo(int).max).min(axis=0)
# array([1, 5, 3], dtype=int64)
```

`np.inf` is not an integer so would force an undesirable upcast.

```
np.where(V>0, U, np.inf).min(axis=0)
# array([1., 5., 3.])
```

Step-by-step:

```
np.iinfo(int)
# iinfo(min=-9223372036854775808, max=9223372036854775807, dtype=int64)

np.where(V>0, U, np.iinfo(int).max)
# array([[                  1, 9223372036854775807,                   3],
#        [                  4,                   5,                   6],
#        [9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775807,                   9],
#        [9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775807,                  12]],
#       dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a task for [masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html):

```
np.amin(np.ma.masked_array(U, V <= 0), axis=0)
```

---

Let's compare the performance of the proposed approaches:

```
import numpy as np
from time_stats import compare_calls

U = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
V = np.array([[1,-1,1],[1,1,1],[-1,-1,1],[-1,-1,1]])


def masked(U=U, V=V):
    return np.amin(U[mask], axis = 0)

def where1(U=U, V=V):
    mask = np.where(V[:,:] < 0, np.inf, 1)
    return np.amin(U*mask, axis = 1)

def where2(U=U, V=V):
    np.where(V>0, U, np.iinfo(int).max).min(axis=0)


r = compare_calls(['masked()', 'where1()', 'where2()'], globals=globals())
print(r)
r.hist()

# masked() : 0.0001 s/call median, 9.7e-05 ... 0.00016 IQR
# where1() : 1e-05 s/call median, 1e-05 ... 1.1e-05 IQR
where2() : 9.6e-06 s/call median, 9.1e-06 ... 1e-05 IQR
```

[image]

Using `where` is clearly faster than masked arrays for this matrix size :)
The difference gets smaller with larger matrices, but @PaulPanzer's solution is always fastest.

E.g. for 1000x1000 matrices:

```
# masked() : 0.015 s/call median, 0.015 ... 0.016 IQR
# where1() : 0.017 s/call median, 0.017 ... 0.02 IQR
# where2() : 0.011 s/call median, 0.01 ... 0.013 IQR
```

Comment: thanks for this, appreciate the quantitative comparison!

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the prettiest solution, but it works ;-)

```
mask = np.where(V[:,:] < 0, np.inf, 1)
x = np.amin(U*mask, axis = 1)
```